# How to combine these two commands to remove first and last seconds from a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to remove the first and last seconds of some videos.
To remove the first seconds, use:

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i file.mp4 -c copy out.mp4
```

To remove the last seconds, use:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -ss 30 -i file.mp4 -c copy -map 1:0 -map 0 -shortest -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - -map 0 -map -0:0 -c copy out.mp4
```

How can I join these commands?

Can I do it in batch?